# Is it a valid REST API URL?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am implementing a **REST** API that return a JSON containing the list of some commodities sold in a country.

I am asking if this kind of URL is good for the pourpose and feed with the **RESTfull** principles to resources access:

```
http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ:RRR/country/1/commodities
```

Where 1 is the country ID.

Could be a good solution or have I to change something?

Comment: This URI is just as "RESTful" as `some-protocol://some.server.pld/djo/bah/eno` and a real REST client doesn't care how the URI is build up or what it's semantics are. The client should instead lookup the meaning of a returned URI via its relation name in the media type a document was returned for and hence decide whether to invoke that URI or not. Anything else just couples the client to the API and thus make the idea behind REST meaningless. As REST is not tide to URI design at all, any answers on the design of your URI is more or less personal taste

Comment: The answer here is unfortunately: it depends... maybe?

There's nothing inherently NOT restful about your approach, but it depends on how the commodities resource will be used in the greater context of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL itself cannot be considered RESTful.

---

Following the common practice, you should have `/countries` (which maps a collection of countries) and `/countries/{id}` (which maps a single country with the given identifier).

But enforcing this convention won't make you application RESTful.

Comment: No I have a collection of commodities related to a single specific country

Comment: @AndreaNobili Not sure about the semantics of your URL then. Following the common practice, you would have `/countries` (which maps a collection of countries) and `/countries/{id}` (which maps a single country with the given identifier).

Comment: @AndreaNobili: I think it is ok to drill down deeper into your data the way you suggest in order to get related records. But as said before there is not really a rule about URLs in the REST definition other then that the same URL should always return the same resource and state. There is not one single best practice either. There are many, many approaches (and a lot of arguments about them). I think your approach is clean and viable. Of course it is good to stick to a commonly used pattern.